# Trying to put stats in a character sheet

Tags: python

I'm making an RPG and I'd like to call up a character sheet function. I've stored the stats in a list, and I'm trying to put them in the sheet:

```
global char
char = ["Name" , 100,100,30,30]

def sheet():
    global char
    print("Character sheet: \nName: {} \nHP: {}/{} \nMP: {}/{}".format(char[0:])
```

I expected it to come out like this:

```
Character sheet:
Name: Name
HP: 100/100
MP: 30/30
```

But it ends up with an error:

```
Tuple index out of range
```

I realize I could do it separately,

```
print("print("Charecter sheet: \nName: {} \nHP: {}/{} \nMp: {}/{}".format(char[0],char[1],...)
```

But I'd be interested in other ways to make my code look cleaner.

Comment: Did you mean `.format(*char)`?

Comment: I'm not great at python so I don't know what that means, could you explain for me?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/36901/3001761

Comment: You don't need and should not use global.

Comment: Can you explain the global thing? I couldn't get to work without it.

Comment: @JohnZuniga, if you remove both globals and use `*char` your code will work fine, the char list is already in the global namespace so it can be accessed in the function no problem.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/291978/short-description-of-python-scoping-rules

Comment: Ahh okay, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are passing only one value to `format` (your list slice `char[0:]` which is the same as `char`) but want to format your output-string with 5 values. Unpack the values.

```
print("Character sheet: \nName: {} \nHP: {}/{} \nMP: {}/{}".format(*char))
```

Also, your last `print` statement lacks a closing parenthesis, I fixed that in my answer.

Comment: @JohnZuniga np, happy coding. Please note the comments on your question regarding the use of `global`.